# Java polymorphism error?

Tags: java, oop

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void move(int speed);
}

class C1 extends Animal {
    public void move(int speed) {
    }
}

class Cat extends C1 {
    public void move() {
        super.move(2);
    }
}

Cat c = new Cat();
// c.move();
```

But I cannot call `c.move()`; why?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: // c.move();
I cannot call it ? Why ?

Comment: @user1832879 Do you get an error?

Comment: You can edit your question. Please edit it so that it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

// c.move();

This should be either in a method/constructor body.

```
public static void main(string[] args) {
Cat c = new Cat();
 c.move();
}
```